# POS-терминал ICD-2002 вывод из bash через /dev/ttyS0

Tags: linux, bash, com-port, rs232

Есть **POS**-терминал **ICD-2002**, принцип работы с которым напоминает принцип работы с матричным принтером через **COM**-порт.
http://pos.kraftway.ru/product/kraftway_icd_2002
На него есть документация с подробным описанием команд.
http://posimages.kraftway.ru/manuals/ICD2002/User%20manual%20ICD-2002.pdf
Но при этом в этой документации нет простейшего примера вывода сообщения.

Допустим, у меня все 8 переключателей установлены в **OFF**, что соответствует скорости **9600bps**, типу команд **ICD-2002** и кодировке **U.S.A**, и **/dev/ttyS0** (единственный **COM**-порт в системе) доступен на запись.

Как мне вывести строку **Test** на него?

```
echo -ne '\x1B\x40\x1B\x52\x30\x54\x65\x73\x74' > /dev/ttyS0

1B 40 (Очистка)
1B 52 30h (Кодировка U.S.A.)
54h 65h 73h 74h (Test в кодировке U.S.A.)

#!/usr/bin/python3
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, dsrdtr=True)
print(ser)
ser.write(b'\x1B\x40\x1B\x52\x30\x54\x65\x73\x74')
ser.close()

Serial<id=0x7f7fe6c088d0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=True)
```

Правильную ли я последовательность вообще передаю, ожидая получить **Test** на терминале?

Comment: Проверьте bytesize. Для us ascii 7 бит достаточно, возможно этом проблема.

Answer (score 1):

ESC - это не строка из трех символов, а один символ с кодом 26 (1B hex).

`echo -e "\x1B\x40 test" > /dev/ttyS0` по идее должно очистить дисплей и вывести test, если порт сконфигурирован верно

> The echo -e command enables the interpretation of backslash escapes

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, но на терминале никаких изменений, даже очистки нет.
Я попробовал нечто такое `echo -e "\x1B \x40 \x1B \x52 \x54 \x65 \x73 \x74" > /dev/ttyS0` Но тоже ничего.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, во-первых, должно быть без пробелов, во-вторых желательно использовать `echo -ne` чтобы перевод строки не добавлялся, а в-третьих порт `stty`'м настроен (документация утилиты довольно паршивая)? хотя 9600 8n1 должны быть характеристиками по умолчанию.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Благодарю за подсказку, но и без пробелов не работает. stty -aF /dev/ttyS0 показывает следующее

stty -aF /dev/ttyS0
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;

Comment: А вообще известно, что  устройство рабочее, порт компа рабочий, кабель? Последнюю пару можно проверить с помощью заглушки - просто 2,3 контакты txd/rxd перемкнуть и проверить приём эха при отправке символа в порт.

Comment: @MBo К сожалению, я и в этом не уверен. COM-порт никогда не использовал (в BIOS включен), терминал тоже негде проверить, но главное нечем но он новый, мусор при включении отображает, светится и видимых повреждений провода нет. Расскажите, пожалуйста по подробнее какую команду мне отправить на замкнутые 2,3 контакты и какой ожидать ответ в случае успеха?

Comment: Бывает, например, что для компорта разъём на плате есть, а с разъемом на задней стенко он шлейфом не соединен (посколько компорты сейчас редко кому нужны). Взять любую терминальную программу, замкнуть проволочкой 2,3 контакты разъема и послать любой текст - он же должен и приняться.

Comment: @MBo В качестве монитора `cat /dev/ttyS0` в качестве устройства отправки `echo -ne 'Test' > /dev/ttyS0`, при разомкнутом на монитор ничего не выводится, при замыкании 2 и 3 и отправке, на мониторе печатается отправляемый Test. Итого COM-порт исправен, `/dev/ttyS0` именно тот самый порт, доступ на запись в этот порт у текущего пользователя есть.

Comment: OK. Если есть приборы (хоть вольтметр-тестер), и кабельный разъем разборный,  можно ещё проверить уровень DTR на терминале (седьмая нога разъема DB-9 относительно пятой ноги). При включении прибора он должен дернуться на некоторое время, потом вернуться в ноль. Если не ноль, то терминал данные не принимает.

Comment: @MBo Мультиметр есть, но вот с разъёмами проблема. Раскручивать терминал и сбивать пломбу не хотелось бы, и на компьютере на метеринской плате подобраться к выводам разъёма проблематично. В измерениях на не подключённом COM-порте, как я понял, нет смысла.

Comment: В измерениях на не подключённом COM-порте есть смысл, если питание подать. Однако шанс встретить такую проблему мал. Я бы ещё раз проверил конфигурацию.

Comment: Ко всему вышесказанному, я бы всё же набросал примерчик на Си или попробовал поговорить с портом minicom'ом, а не голым шелом дабы исключить неверную настрройку порта...

Comment: Эх накидал на пайтоне, но безрезультатно. :-(

`Serial<id=0x7f7fe6c088d0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=True)`

Comment: Документацию не читал, но вы уверены, что его никак не надо особенным образом инитить до этого? И что-то я не вижу указания размера текста, что обычно в таких протоколах нужно. Фирменного софта нет конечно?

Comment: @bukkojot Нет, в этом я тоже не уверен. В документации описываются настройки порта `The default protocol is 9600 bps, non-parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit and with DTR/DSR control.` Положение8-ми контактного переключателя и описания команд для встроенного языка. Но ни одного примера и не объясняется зачем нужны те или иные команды и в каком порядке и как их нужно использовать. :-( http://posimages.kraftway.ru/manuals/ICD2002/User%20manual%20ICD-2002.pdf
Я никогда не работал с матричными принтерами и COM-протом и не уверен даже правильно ли я отправляю команды в виде последовательностей.

Comment: Время долбить саппорт?